# vb.net No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: vb.net

I am download a Json libary here : http://www.pozzware.com/pozzware/Corsi/Programmazione/VB.NET/JSON%20Library.aspx

This is my class on my project :

```
Imports PW.JSON

Public Class Prova

Private _id As Integer
Private _name As String
Private _valido As Boolean
Private _subObject As Prova
Private _numero As Integer
Private _numeroDec As Double
Private _array() As String

Public Property ID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _id
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _id = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _name = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Valido() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _valido
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _valido = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SubObject() As Prova
    Get
        Return _subObject
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Prova)
        _subObject = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property NumeroDec() As Double
    Get
        Return _numeroDec
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        _numeroDec = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Array() As String()
    Get
        Return _array
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String())
        _array = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New(ByVal ID As Integer, ByVal Name As String)
    _id = ID
    _name = Name
End Sub

Public Function SomeMethod() As String
    Return "Method: " & _id
End Function

End Class
```

And this is my code :

```
Sub PasteJsonExam()
    Dim strJSON As String = "{""NumeroDec"": 100.34, ""Name"": ""Nome Object"", " & _
                            " ""Array"": [""A"", ""E"", ""I"", ""O"", ""U""], " & _
                            " ""SubObject"": {""NumeroDec"": 0, ""Name"": ""Nome - SubObject"", " & _
                            " ""Array"": null, ""SubObject"": null, ""Valido"": false, ""ID"": 2}, " & _
                            " ""Valido"": true, ""ID"": 1}"

    Dim objprova As Prova
    objprova = PW.JSON.JSONHelper.StringToObject(strJSON, GetType(Prova))
    MsgBox(objprova.Name)
    MsgBox(objprova.SubObject.Name)
End Sub
```

When i call that sub i got error :

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

At this line :

```
objprova = PW.JSON.JSONHelper.StringToObject(strJSON, GetType(Prova))
```

I am not an professonal in VB.net so i hope someone explain for me why i got that error and how can i fix this.

Comment: Use NewtonJson instead. Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Just add a Sub New() without parameters

Comment: Almost everyone, including ASP.NET Web API projects, uses JSon.NET. Why are you trying to use a snippet written 6 years ago? For example, that snippet doesn't handle dates

Comment: You must add the default constructor.

Comment: The error message itself is *VERY* clear. You need to define a default constructor. This has nothing to do with JSON

Answer (score 1):

Probably `StringToObject` method try to create an instance of `Prova`. It does this by calling the default(parameterless) constructor of the type.
But in the class you defined there isn't any parameterless constructor, you have only:

```
Public Class Prova
    ' Other fields and methods
    Public Sub New(ByVal ID As Integer, ByVal Name As String)
        _id = ID
        _name = Name
    End Sub
    ' Other fields and methods
End Class
```

To let the method work you need to define a parameterless constructor like:

```
Public Class Prova
    ' Other fields and methods
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal ID As Integer, ByVal Name As String)
        _id = ID
        _name = Name
    End Sub
    ' Other fields and methods
End Class
```

Comment: Dear ! please how can i fix this ?

Comment: @DươngTrần As I posted you need to define a parameterless constructor like `Public Sub New()`

Comment: Dear ! i can not edit bacause i have more sub need to call like this : `Sub JoinJsonExam()
        Dim objprova As New Prova(1, "Nome Object")
        objprova.Array = Split("A E I O U")
        objprova.NumeroDec = 100.34
        objprova.SubObject = New Prova(2, "Nome - SubObject")
        objprova.Valido = True
        MsgBox(PW.JSON.JSONHelper.ObjectToString(objprova))
    End Sub`

Comment: @DươngTrần You don't need to remove your constructor with parameters, just add another constructor (I edited my answer to be more clear)

Answer (score 0):

Well i think that the library you are using is not the best choice, but, if you want to run your program you must add a **default constructor** (a constructor without parameter). That's because the library probably uses **Reflection**

This is the class with the Default Constructor:

```
Imports PW.JSON

Public Class Prova

Private _id As Integer
Private _name As String
Private _valido As Boolean
Private _subObject As Prova
Private _numero As Integer
Private _numeroDec As Double
Private _array() As String

Public Property ID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _id
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _id = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _name = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Valido() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _valido
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _valido = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SubObject() As Prova
    Get
        Return _subObject
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Prova)
        _subObject = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property NumeroDec() As Double
    Get
        Return _numeroDec
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        _numeroDec = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Array() As String()
    Get
        Return _array
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String())
        _array = value
    End Set
End Property

' This is the default constructor the library should need'
Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal ID As Integer, ByVal Name As String)
    _id = ID
    _name = Name
End Sub

Public Function SomeMethod() As String
    Return "Method: " & _id
End Function

End Class
```